# How add GRASS functions to QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, function

In my toolbox doesn't exist any grass function, what act I should do?

Comment: Did you see any menu when you select **Plugins-> GRASS** of top Menu Toolbar.

Comment: Yes , I see. I install QGIS 2.6 then installed GRASS 6.4.4 but I guess they didn't relate with each other. My toolbox hasn't any GRASS function. When I open it the software ask me to introduce the direction of grass but any direction didn't accept by QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the grass functions linked properly within qgis? Check the path in Processing -> Options -> Providers -> Grass commands. It should be assigned to the grass folder in the qgis installation. In my case: C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\grass\grass-7.2.0

Comment: yes I checked it, they are installed

Comment: And what is the path assigned to _Grass folder_?
Is the box _Activate_ above checked?

Comment: Yes I checked it, the problem was the processing toolbox was in the standard mood , I changed it to advance interface. Thank you my friend